# Is there a difference between pyenv activate and pyenv local?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I know that to activate a virtual environment with pyenv, we can run `pyenv activate [virtualenv]`, but [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/managing-virtual-environment-with-pyenv-ae6f3fb835f8), i also saw that we can "select" a virtual environment by running `pyenv local [virtualenv]`.

So what is the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base command is [`pyenv local <python_version>`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local). It selects what Python version to use in the current directory or its subdirectories.

[`pyenv activate <name>`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) activates a Python virtual environment.

`pyenv local <venv-name>` [works](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv#activate-virtualenv) after `pyenv virtualenv venv-name` and `eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"` in shell configuration. After the command the `<venv-name>` (a virtual environment known to `pyenv`) is activated when entering (with `cd`) the directory where `pyenv local <venv-name>` had been run.

Comment: There’s a pyenv local venv-name command actually. I just found out that the difference is that this command automatically activates the virtual environment. Thanks though !

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out [here](https://medium.com/codex/python-version-management-with-pyenv-and-pyenv-virtualenv-linux-ecd6578b7bbf) that the difference is that this command automatically activates the virtual environment. Thank you!